# Restoring Maildir emails from backup on different machine (so filename conventions differ)

Tags: diff, merge, maildir

I have GMail synced via IMAP using offlineimap on Machine A and Machine B.  I accidentally deleted 5000 messages when trying to sync Machine B.  Machine A was off at the time, and so I still have those messages.  The problem is that Machine A and Machine B give the emails different filenames in their Maildirs.

A more abstract description of the problem is that I want to merge two directory trees, by considering only the *contents of the files*, and ignoring the filenames.

Unfortunately I'm not sure that there is anything in the filenames that can reliably identify its match in the other directory tree.

(one possible route that I will try is to simply re-sync Machine A and then restore the emails from its own backup.  Then I won't have the filename problem!  But now I find this question interesting so I will post it anyway)

Comment: As you told you used to sync via IMAP, i suppose both Machine A and B have a IMAP server running. So you should be able to use `imapsync.pl` from the `imap_tools`package at http://www.athensfbc.com/imap_tools/